# Can you extract the www folder from a cordova app downloaded from the app store

Tags: android, ios, cordova, google-play, app-store

I know that building the app for debug mode will allow me to use Chrome (android version) or Safari (iOS version) for debugging, which will allow me to see the javascript and filesystem in the app.

I also discovered I can open the `*.xcarchive` file that was built, browse into it's `*.app` file, and see the `www` folder in there. (I'm not sure how to dig into android.)

When a user downloads our app from the app store or the play store, is there a way for them to do the same thing? Or is the app encrypted or locked so the internals cannot be inspected?

I don't keep anything particularly sensitive in there but URLs and facebook client ids are still worth hiding.

Answer (score 1):

An APK is basically a zip folder. So yes, anyone who can download your .apk can open it and view what's inside of it. There are also mirrors of the Google Play Store out there where you can download an archive of an apk. It wouldb't be very hard to recreate a debug-able build from your source. You can (and should) at least minify/obfuscate your code if possible.